# datepicker days and date logic for jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datepicker

on the on _change event of from_date i want to fetch the value of input days and from_date to add the value of days and from_date and set it to to_date

for example input_days=5 and from_date=10/02/2020 it should add and automatically display 15/02/2020 in to_date....

here is the code which adds from_date and to_date and displays total_date but... what should i change in this logic?

```
$("#fromdate,#todate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
});

$("#fromdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
$("#todate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});

$('#enddate').change(function () {
    var start = $('#fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#todate').datepicker('getDate');

    if (start < end) {
        var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#total_days').val(days);
    } else {

        alert("cannot select same or previous date!");
        $('#fromdate').val("");
        $('#total_days').val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below code. Also please find fiddle link in comment. If input is blank I am adding 5 days by default.

```
<label class="required">Days</label> <input type="text" id="days"><br/><br/><br/>
<label class="required">from</label>                                                                                                           
<input type="text" id="fromDate" class="form-control date-picker from input-append minDate" placeholder="mm/yyyy"><br/><br/><br/>

<label> To </label>                                             
<input type="text" id="toDate" class="form-control date-picker to input-append maxDate" placeholder="mm/yyyy" >

$(function() {
    $( ".from" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        var toDate = $('.from').datepicker('getDate');
        var days = $("#days").val()  != "" ? parseInt($("#days").val()) : 5;
                toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + days );
                $('.to').datepicker('setDate', toDate);
      }
    });
    $( ".to" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Fiddle link for above answer https://jsfiddle.net/shivpatne/7g8paL6j

Comment: i have another <input type="text" id="days"> i am passing $("#days").val() instead of + 5 but this is not giving the proper output

Comment: .val() gives you string. You need to parse it to integer.

Comment: I have updated fiddle and my code in answer too. Where you can provide days value using input box

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = $("#fromdate").val(); // your input date ID, like we have input: 5
var myDate = new Date($.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date($('#fromdate').datepicker('getDate'))));
var d = myDate.getDate()+parseInt(val, 10);
var m =  myDate.getMonth()+1;
var y = myDate.getFullYear();
$("#todate").val(new Date(yy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd));
```

Comment: this works but i just want the value of to_date to be in the format yy/mm/dd instead its showing Sat Feb 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: try now, i have updated $("#todate").val(new Date(yy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd));

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        jQuery( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    jQuery("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        jQuery( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text" id="from">
<input type="text" id="to">

<script  type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('#txtFromDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: 'd',
        minDate: new Date('today'),
        language: locale,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
    $('#txtToDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: '+2d',/change value for to 5 for 5 days
        minDate: '#txtToDate',
        viewMode: 'years',
        language: locale,
        autoclose: true,
    });
```